# how to add multiple hyperlinks in image placed inside single excel cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

i have an image inside excel 2013 as shown below:

[image]

i want to make multiple body parts hyperlink or behave as a button insight this single image.

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: A series of transparent rectangles over each area, with hyperlinks from them? (just use one wide one to cover both shoulders, one for both arms etc unless you need left and right separately)

Comment: how to make rectangle transparent?

Comment: yes, i did it, thank for help. really appreciated.